# Charting multiple y Values from a single csv file

Tags: c#, csv, charts, mschart

I am having trouble plotting multiple Y values on a single chart.  The following code works for just a  single y value but will not plot multiple y values from the same csv datafile.

The format for the csv file is:
datestamp, value 1, value 2, value 3

I can get the chart to show the datestamp vs any column y data point in the csv file but will not show other y values.

Yes, it is clear I new to OOP and winforms but I am trying.  Back in the day when I was programming it was Fortran on PDP11.

Anyway, this piece of code is from here somewhere but I have not been able to find the answer I am looking for

The form is a chart control and a button.

Thanks for your help

7/27.
This piece of code works but is there a better way to load multiple Y values?

Also, the code has been broken up by the revision.

If loading them into a datatable, then bind the datatable to the chart.  Will this not take up space in memory?

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Full path to the data source file
        string file = "testlog2.csv";
        string path = @"g:\";
        // Create a connection string.
        string filepPathConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            path + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=CSVDelimited\"";
        // Create Connection Object
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(filepPathConnectStr);

        // Create a database command on the connection using query
        string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

        // Open the connection and create the reader
        myCommand.Connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // Column 1 is a time value, column 2 is a double
        // databind the reader to the chart using the DataBindXY method
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "0", myReader, "1");
        //Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindY(myReader, "3");


        myReader.Close();
```

myConnection.Close();

```
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Full path to the data source file
        string file = "testlog2.csv";
        string path = @"g:\";
        // Create a connection string.
        string filepPathConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            path + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=CSVDelimited\"";
        // Create Connection Object
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(filepPathConnectStr);

        // Create a database command on the connection using query
        string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

        // Open the connection and create the reader
        myCommand.Connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // Column 1 is a time value, column 2 is a double
        // databind the reader to the chart using the DataBindY method

        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindY(myReader, "3");

        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only data binding points from 1 y column. If you want to show multiple y columns, you can do one of two things:

1. Instead of databinding, add points manually. This would entail looping through all rows in your csv, and adding 2 (or more) points for each row:

   ```
   series.Points.AddXY(csvLine[0], csvLine[3]);
   series.Points.AddXY(csvLine[0], csvLine[4]);
   ```

You could change the color of the points in different columns to distinguish them, but the legend would not reflect the different colors.

1. Create multiple `Series` objects, and databind each one to a different y column. Something like

   ```
   Series series2 = chart1.Series.Add("Series2");
   series2.Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "0", myReader, "4");
   ```

You could then set the properties of `series2` to have a different color, etc. This is the preferred way as it handles a lot of stuff for you.